# CSS - How do I position my 'a' element text in a Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position my `a` element text inside of a Bootstrap `navbar` but, so far, I have achieved an `a` element with 15px padding on all sides and a height of 0.

I am trying to implement a 'tabs bar' where a new tab is created every time a user clicks on an option in a separate navbar, so the `li` and `a` elements for the tab are added dynamically using JQuery.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
@* Navbar -- Tabs Bar *@
<nav class="navbar tabsBar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav tabbar-nav">

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".btnSwitchView a").click(function () {
    var tabName = $(this).data("name");
    var newTab = "<li id='" + tabName + "' class='tab'><a href='#'>" + tabName + "</a></li>";
    $(".tabbar-nav").append(newTab);
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.tabsBar {
    background-color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    min-height: 30px !important;
}

.tabbar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.tab {
    display: block;
    margin-right: .7em;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #222222;
    text-align: center;
}

.tab a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    color: gray;
}
```

Here is a picture of the result:

[image: not what I want]
I want the text to centered horizontally and vertically in the box, and the box to be sitting on the bottom of the bar.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much CSS code and actually those heights and widths properties are the problem, especially this line: min-height: 30px !important;, which gives the nav exactly a height of 30px, because your nav is empty.

Try this:

```
.tabsBar {
    background-color: gray;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.tabbar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}

.tab {
    margin-right: .7em;
    background-color: #222222;
    text-align: center;
}

.tab a {
    color: gray;
}
```

This is the result tested in chrome and firefox
[image]